# Python: How to pause a while True loop?

Tags: loops, sleep, python-3.2

So I'm making a python version of cookie clicker :D
To add the cps to the cookies counter, I use this code:

```
while True:
    cps = b1*1 + b2*5 + b3*10 + b4*20 + b5*25
    c=c+cps
    time.sleep(60)
    print('you now have %s cookies' %c)
```

note: the b1, b2 etc and the amounts of different cookie producers

Problem is, the time.sleep pauses the whole script, not just the while loop you can see above

BTW this is my first post, sorry if I did something wrong :/
Thanks for reading this :P

Comment: "pauses the whole script" ? what would you expect it to pause ? part of the script ?

Comment: "sleep pauses the whole script" It's true for single threaded script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make a method for this loop then start a new thread for this after that you can just simply cal .sleep() which will only make that thread suspend for the given time not the whole code.
Check the [Link](http://pymotw.com/2/threading/) it will help about multi-threading.

```
import threading

def worker():
    """your code in this method"""


t = threading.Thread(target=worker)
t.start()
```

Comment: hmmm... never heard of threading before. Could you give me an example of it with my code please?

Comment: Did you check the link I attached?

Comment: just one more question :/
If I make that a thread, will I need to make everything else a different thread?

Comment: No no not necessarily.

Answer (score 0):

AS far as i can see you have two options:

1. You measure the time between each call to update the cookieamount c and multiply it accordingly.
2. You make a new thread. Then sleep will just pause your thread to update your cookieamount.